# UPDATE time column using STRFTIME does not work

Tags: sqlite, date, strftime

I tried to update a value in table "date" column "time". The date should change from (i.e.)

"2019-01-31 08:00" to "2021-01-31 08:00"

, but it does not. I read the SQLite-reference. Is STRFTIME not allowed for such an operation?

```
UPDATE date SET time=STRFTIME('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm', time, '+2 years') WHERE id=735
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the format like this:

```
UPDATE date SET time=STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', time, '+2 years') WHERE id=735
```

more info in this [link](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/functions/strftime.php)

Comment: WOW, superfast. I just saw it when I read the docu again and want to answer my question, but you have been faster than Flash. Thanx.